# Unable to drill down into a variable in Firebug

Tags: javascript, api, firebug

Occasionally in firebug I'm unable to drill down into a variable expression when stepping through javascript code. Sometimes it's flukey behavior and I'll refresh the page and the next time through I am able to drill down. However with some variables I'm never able to. I'll give an example:

I'm using the google visualization api and I have the following code:

```
var row = tableChart1.getSelection();
var test5 = queryWrapper1;

var dt = test5.currentDataTable;
var dv = test5.currentDataView;

var x = dv.getViewRowIndex(row[0].row);
var y = dt.getRowProperties(row[0].row);
alert(test5.currentDataTable.getRowProperty(row[0].row,"ticker"));
```

The variable that I'm not able to drill down into is y. Here's the documentation for getRowProperties() (here's the link [link to documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable)):

> Returns: Object
>
> Returns a map of all properties for the specified row. Note that the
>   properties object is returned by reference, so changing values in the
>   retrieved object changes them in the DataTable.

Any explanation as to why firebug won't let me examine the properties of the returned object would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Update: I'm using firebug 1.7.3.

Also here's a screen shot of what I'm seeing: [image: screenshot]

Comment: You forgot to declare "y" with `var`. That makes it a global variable.

Comment: y was actually declared prior to the block of code that I inserted. But whether it's global or local shouldn't make a difference as to firebug's ability to inspect it.

Comment: Looks like y is just an empty object. Are you sure getRowProperties returns anything useful at all?

Comment: Could be a bug in the google api...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried testing it a bit with some example code from Google. It's not an issue with Firebug. The `object` that gets returned from your call to `dt.getRowProperties(row[0].row);` really is empty. The documentation on [getRowProperty](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable_getRowProperty) mentions that `null` is returned if no such property exists. It seems that an empty object is returned for the related function `getRowProperties`, if there are no properties.

The properties of a row, column, or cell are used by some visualizations to change their behavior, as [explained in the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable_setRowProperty). You have to explicitly set these properties with the relevant functions.

If you want to test it out, to prove that it isn't Firebug, change the code like so:

```
var row = tableChart1.getSelection();
var test5 = queryWrapper1;

var dt = test5.currentDataTable;
var dv = test5.currentDataView;

var x = dv.getViewRowIndex(row[0].row);

// Add this bit
dt.setRowProperty(row[0].row, 'foo', 'bar');

var y = dt.getRowProperties(row[0].row);
alert(test5.currentDataTable.getRowProperty(row[0].row,"ticker"));
```